# Sum of multiple collection Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-8

I wish to get the sum of multiple collection

```
$collection1 = collect([1, 2, 3]);
$collection2 = collect([4, 8, 1]);
$collection3 = collect([5, 7, 1]);
```

I wish the result like that

```
$collection = [10,17,5];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can merge all collections in an array, this code help you:

```
$newColl = collect([0, 0, 0]);
foreach([$collection1, $collection2, $collection3] as $coll){
    for($i = 0; $i < $coll->count(); $i++){
         $newColl[$i] += $coll[$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$number_of_collections = x;
    for($i=1 ; $i<=$number_of_collections ; $i++){
         $collection[$i] = $collection1[$i]+$collection2[$i]+$collection3[$i];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you is there a way to merge and sum multiple collections ?

Comment: you can make it more dynamic ... i'll edit my answer